# Difference between "Level" and "Flow" in the Z.1 Fed data

Tags: data-request, federal-reserve

The Z.1 Fed data can be found [in FRED](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/tags/series?t=z1).

I notices that many similar data sets are labelled "Flow" or "Level". For example,

- [Financial business; total liabilities, Flow](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/FBTLLIQ027S)
- [Federal government; total liabilities, Level](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/FGTLBLQ027S)
- [Financial business; total financial assets, Level](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/FBTFASQ027S)

And sometimes, the Level version for a Flow series doesn't exist or vice verse.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a balance sheet that measures a country's total stock of financial assets and liabilities for a given year. If you have a bunch of these balance sheets for several years, those data points are the actual **levels** of total assets/liabilities.

Now suppose you decide to subtract the levels that correspond to year $t-1$ from the levels that correspond to year $t$. That's what the Fed is doing with these data series -- the **flows** are the *first-difference* of the levels.